# Android - Opening Default Music Library Properly

Tags: android

In my Android application I have a button which should open the Music Library of device.
I'm using the following code now

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

I understand that there can be devices without default music library.
So, I want the code snippet which will open music library if it is  possible and show some message(or something else), otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Surround it in a try/catch block. If an `ActivityNotFoundException` is thrown, then there is no component on the device capable of receiving that intent:

```
 try {
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
     startActivity(intent);
 catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
     // Handle no component found here (e.g. show a toast or dialog)
 }
```

Comment: You may also require the intent to have a category of `Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT`, you'd have to test this on a device.